# How to find rows of matrix that are zero everywhere except for 1 entry?

Tags: algorithms, matrices

I am interested in finding the rows of a matrix where all entries are equal to zeros except for one.

Example: Given the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}0  &0 &3 & 8\\ 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &1 & 0  & 1\end{bmatrix}

Only the second line has this property.

Of course, the brute force way is to go over the entries and check them one by one. But I am wondering if there is another most efficient way I don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

There is no algorithm with worst-case running time better than $O(n^2)$.  There is a simple adversary argument to prove this.

Consider any algorithm that is purported to be correct, and that always inspects fewer than $n^2$ entries of the matrix. Thus, there must always be some entry that is uninspected.  Consider a matrix that has 1's in the entire first column.  Every time the algorithm inspects any other entry, it will find a 0.  After inspecting at most $n^2-1$ entries, the algorithm terminates and outputs some list of rows.  Pick any entry that was uninspected.  Now we have a freedom about whether to fill it in with a 0 or a 1; and we can always make a choice that will make the algorithm's output wrong (if the algorithm included that row in its output, make it a 1; otherwise make it a 0).  So, for any correct algorithm, it must inspect all matrix entries for at least some inputs, so its running time must be at least $\Omega(n^2)$.

There are various optimizations you can use in practice, like using bitwise operations (depending on how the matrix is stored), and if you see more than a single 1 in any row, don't look at any other entries in that row -- but these won't affect the asymptotic worst-case running time.

Answer (score 1):

This is no different than asking for an algorithm for deciding if the entries of an array contain a nonzero. So what you describe is optimal, i.e. an adversary argument shows that any algorithm must examine each entry for otherwise you can't know for sure.